# How to remove the backslash (“\”) in the json response ,Objective C?

Tags: ios

How to remove  backslash(/)?. Every parameter is coming with backslash.All values stored in dictionary

```
 ex:getCategoryListReturn" :"[{\"categoryId\":734, \"categoryNm\":\"Projector Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"تجار العارض\/مسلاط\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":735,\"categoryNm\":\"Computer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"تجار  الحاسب الآلي \",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":736,\"categoryNm\":\"Laptop Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"تجار الحاسب الآلي\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":737,\"categoryNm\":\"Printer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"الطباعة\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":738,\"categoryNm\":\"Colour Printer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"تجار الطباعة الملونة\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":739,\"categoryNm\":\"Laser Printer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"الطباعة بالليزر\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":740,\"categoryNm\":\"All In One Printer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"اعمال الطباعة \",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":741,\"categoryNm\":\"Colour Laser Printer Dealers\",\"categoryNmBl\":\"الطباعة الملونة\",\"prntCategoryId\":733},{\"categoryId\":}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using debug output of some sort, which shows a string with all double-quotes escaped. The actual string contains no backslashes.

Comment: just use NSJSONSerialization, it will give you proper json.

Comment: Really thanks for your comments...I have fixed that error.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but for me the problem was using GSON library for JSON conversion. I solved the issue at server end.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below code to remove backslash(/n)

```
NSData *data1 = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"getCategoryListReturn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
```